# SQLSERVER Identity Column values Jumping by millions

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, identity-column

I have table with an int identity column and it is skipping id in thousands at times. Searches suggest it is normal of sql server to skip it by 1000 or 1001, but mine does increase by 20000 or more on occasions, But last time it got jumped by **95216000**.

Unable to find reason why this is happening, check sql server for crash logs and any other suspicious events but no luck.

Having replication on table, is that related..??

Create Table Script is like..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [CId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    .

 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: show your table structure script. also let us know what are you trying to do

Comment: Are you doing a lot of rollbacked transactions in between the records that you are comparing?

Comment: added create table script in discription...

Comment: not doing any large transaction rollbacks.. just inserts and that are too very low.. up to 500 /day.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked values for this

```
SELECT IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS Seed,
IDENT_INCR(TABLE_NAME) AS Increment,
IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_NAME) AS Current_Identity,
TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'YourTableName') = 1
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Also by any chance you truncated the data into table?

Comment: query returned Seed=1, Increment=1, Current_Identity=95849977. I have replication running for db, a publication and push subscription, is this have something to do with this,

Comment: Since your Ident_Current is 95849977 it will generate +1 to that number to next insert to that table

Comment: If you did large delete and you need to reseed means you can use this query to reseed to the number you want    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('YourTableName', RESEED, 0)

Comment: i can't reseed, this is a foreign key in various tables, and in naming of saving some related files.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link to find the reason for the gaps.

http://sqlity.net/en/792/the-gap-in-the-identity-value-sequence/

Comment: i suspect on merge replication to be culprit in my scenario, but not sure. One question, If it is related to replication and i try adding -t272 as startup parameter. will that fix it(if i am able to bear performance hamper b adding trace)